# \msg_error: how to have shorter indentation and lines starting with ! for correct handling in TeXstudio

Tags: error-writing

My library uses `\msg_error` (LaTeX3) to create errors like:

```
! Package robExt Error: On line 16: the pdf file
(robExt)               
robustExternalize/robExt-ABC41082ADB6EF46AFE4D61D09630D7A.pdf
(robExt)                is not present. The compilation command "cd
(robExt)                robustExternalize/ && gnuplot -c
(robExt)                "robExt-ABC41082ADB6EF46AFE4D61D09630D7A.tex" &&
(robExt)                echo "ok" >
(robExt)                "robExt-ABC41082ADB6EF46AFE4D61D09630D7A.pdf"" used
(robExt)                to compile the environment on line 16 certainly
(robExt)                failed with errors:
(robExt)                vvvvvv
(robExt)                some random message error from gnuplot
(robExt)                ^^^^^^
(robExt)                See full logs below or in
(robExt)               
robustExternalize/robExt-ABC41082ADB6EF46AFE4D61D09630D7A-compilation.log.
```

But the problem is that TeXstudio does not recognise this as an error (except for the very first line starting with a !). Can I somehow make TeXstudio print this in the error panel (without going to the log), or make all these lines start with `!` since it is what is used by TeXstudio to recognize an error apparently? Also, can I reduce the indentation? There is a huge space after `(robExt)` which makes the error harder to read.

Comment: texstudio is notorious for scrambling tex error messages, it will not even show a basic primitive tex undefined command error without hiding which command is undefined.  You could raise an issue with the editor.

Comment: see https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1410

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if we can somehow provide to texlive a line for the error message? I tried to write `! foo Error: on line 23: bar` but it still can't know where the error is.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz or older.. https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, a prehistoric find!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz how can it be prehistoric and have a post from a young person like me?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Obvious: Joseph, the Time Lord, took you on a trip in his Tardis!

Comment: Actually, is there any official way to parse errors/warnings in LaTeX? Should the line contain the word error? Start with a !? …